# Dynamically computed Bash variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have several similarly structured directory trees.
something like:
  ~/
    Tree1/
       src/
       bin/
    Tree2/
       src/
       bin/

When I somewhere below Tree1/src I want to work with Tree1/bin. When I somewhere below Tree2/src I want to work with Tree2/bin.

Is there a way to define a shell variable whose value depends on my current working directory?

Answer (score 3):

PWD is a variable already set to your current directory by bash, ksh and other shells.

Answer (score 1):

`cwd=$(pwd)` should do the trick. It assigns the output of print working directory (pwd) to a variable.

To replace ~Tree1/src/dir1/dir2  with ~Tree1/bin you could do

```
bindir=$(pwd | sed 's/src.*/bin/')
```

See also [Command Substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html)

Answer (score 1):

As jlliagre stated, bash (as many other modern shells) stores the current working directory in $PWD; if it is Tree1/src/some/other/directory, then you can extract "Tree1/bin" from it by just using "parameter expansion":

```
$ echo $PWD
Tree1/src/some/other/directory

$ echo ${PWD%%src*}bin
Tree1/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally `$PWD` variable (Present Working Directory) contains the path to the current directory. If this variable is not defined, you can use the `pwd` command that will return the current path.

Answer (score 0):

Two other definitions of "current" include the directory you were in when the script was started (which is the value of `start_dir="$PWD"` at the start of the file, no matter where the script is) and the directory of the script itself - `script_dir="$(dirname -- "$(readlink -f -- "$0")")"`.